# Zoom to link button in Popup, killing the Map

Tags: arcgis-maps-sdk-javascript, popup

I am using the [traditional Popup](http://help.arcgis.com/en/webapi/javascript/arcgis/samples/ags_gpxwebmap/index.html) of JavaScript API and it seems to not work properly in my [application](http://msgist2011.grd.arizona.edu/project/tp_dock.html). When you click on the map, the Popup comes fine but when you click on the Zoom to link button, the map zooms in and then if you move the map, the map disappears.

It only returns when you refresh the app. Not sure what is causing it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like a spatial reference issue, your map is in WGS 1984 Web Mercator (Auxiliary Sphere) ("wkid":3857/102100*) and you are asking it to zoom to a 'States' object in a geographic coordinate system ("wkid": 4326  - GCS_WGS_1984.). Either project the states layer in to web mercator or override the zoom function and project the geometry before zooming.

*I would use 102100 to represent WGS 1984 Web Mercator (Auxiliary Sphere). see this [article](http://forums.arcgis.com/threads/8762-WGS-1984-Web-Mercator-%28Auxiliary-Sphere%29-WKID-102100)

Comment: That is it. Thanks a lot. I changed all `wkid` to 102100